# How can i run my method by clicking on button on view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a method:

```
def add_to_favorite(id)
    current_user.update(favorite_photos: current_user.favorite_photos + " " + id)
end
```

This method add something information in end of string current_user.fafavorite_photos.

How can i run this method by clicking on buttor or link in my view? 
Without JS, using only Ruby on Rails.
Thanks.

Comment: I have this method in aplication_helper.rb

Comment: I don't think if you define a method in application_helper and want it to be triggered by `button` or `link` it'll work. One way is to define it as an controller action and do it.

Comment: I don`n know why but this method works only from aplication helper

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a link to call an action.

```
# controller
def add_to_favorite(id)
    current_user.update(favorite_photos: current_user.favorite_photos + " " + id)
end

# routes.rb
put 'favorites/:id/add_to_favorite'

# view
<%= link_to 'Add_Favorite', add_to_favorite_path(@favorite), method: :put %>
```

If you want a button to do it, then

```
<%= form_tag add_to_favorite_path, method: :put do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add_To_Favorite' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Or just style the `link_to` like a button.